I'm trying to pass a Form Object through a subroutine during an OnOpen Event in Access 2007
I have an Access Database in Access 2007 and I'm trying to set read-only access permissions using subroutines. I have this subroutine in each Form I want locked
Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    SetAccess (Form_Routes)

End Sub

and this Public Sub that I want to control the actual form properties.
Public Sub SetAccess(oForm As Object)

    With oForm
        .AllowAdditions = EditAccess
        .AllowDeletions = EditAccess
        .AllowEdits = EditAccess
    End With

End Sub

EditAccess is a boolean value that the user can toggle to prevent accidental edits.
I want to use a single subroutine so if I want to change how the access permissions work, I can change it in one place rather than each form that should get locked as I have almost a dozen forms.
When I Open the form Form_Routes, it returns the error
"Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"
I tested whether it was the form name Form_Routes by replacing oForm with Form_Routes and it works fine but I think I need to pass the form name as an Object variable for this to work the way I envision.
What I want to happen is when the form opens, it checks whether the user has turned on editing and set the appropriate properties.

You might have to move this to on-load, as on-open can read controls, but they can't be modified.


Use the Me keyword to always refer to the form where the code runs in.

DO NOT use parentheses for parameters, unless you use the Call syntax or get a return value from a function.


SetAccess (Form_Routes) evaluates the parameter, changing it from the form object to something else.
Just use:
Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    SetAccess Me

End Sub


Also, be specific: Public Sub SetAccess(oForm As Access.Form).
